# Hyperref for subfloats with subfig package

Tags: hyperref, subfloats

I have a figure with some subfloats. The figure es something like that:

[image]

I have not each subfloat separately, I have a single picture.

For linking the picture with the reference in text I used hyperref:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Figures \ref{Fig1a} and \ref{Fig1b} are in Figure \ref{Fig1}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\subfloat{
\includegraphics{example-image}
\label{Fig1a}
}
\subfloat{\label{Fig1b}}
\caption{Image description:
\textbf{(a)}~figure 1a and 
\textbf{(b)}~figure 1b
}
\label{Fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When I click on `Fig1a` and `Fig1` in the `.pdf` document inmediatelly I am conduced to the figure, but when I click on `Fig1b` I'm conduced to the caption. How can I click on Fig1b and get conduced to the image and not to the caption?

Comment: The problem is that you're using `subfig` and it is known for its issues with `hyperref`. You could e.g. switch to `subcaption`.

Comment: It's not exactly a solution, but if you put \leavevmode in front of the first \subfloat, it will also go to the bottom (same as the second).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how to get the second `\subfloat` into vmode, since that only happens at the end of a line.  Then I thought, a minipage effectively starts a new page (in vmode).

Of course, putting a `\subfloat` inside a minipage is sort of redundant, since it basically **is** a minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Figures \ref{Fig1a} and \ref{Fig1b} are in Figure \ref{Fig1}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\subfloat{
  \includegraphics[width={\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}]{example-image-a}
  \label{Fig1a}
}\hfil
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
  \subfloat{
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \label{Fig1b}
  }
\end{minipage}
\caption{Image description:
\textbf{(a)}~figure 1a and 
\textbf{(b)}~figure 1b
}
\label{Fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

This solution uses minipages only.  It still uses some definitions from the subfig package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\stepsubfigure}{%
  \advance\c@figure by 1 %local
  \refstepcounter{subfigure}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Figures \ref{Fig1a} and \ref{Fig1b} are in Figure \ref{Fig1}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
  \stepsubfigure
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \label{Fig1a}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
  \stepsubfigure
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \label{Fig1b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Image description:
\textbf{(a)}~figure 1a and 
\textbf{(b)}~figure 1b
}
\label{Fig1} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it works, but duplicated th image. Supose that the image already has the image a and the image b

Comment: I added the image to the second \subfloat so that it would actually have some height.